# Export variables to shell in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have the function in Jenkinsfile,

```
def dothis(String ENV) {
    withCredentials([ awsCredentials(), string(credentialsId: "${ENV}-db-root-password", variable: 'DBPASSWORD')]) {
     wrap([$class: 'BuildUser']) {
      dir("scripts") {
        echo "connecting to ${ENV}"
        sh('ENV=$ENV ./rds.sh')
      }
     }
  }
}
```

echo "connecting to ${ENV}" --> this is printing ENV
But sh('ENV=$ENV ./rds.sh') --> is not viewing ENV. ENV goes empty inside this shell.

how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For String interpolation to work you need to wrap the String with double quotes. Hence change the sh step like below.

```bash
sh("ENV=$ENV ./rds.sh")
```